# Can't resolve the Introduction to algorithms problem 1-1

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I'm trying to self-teach CS, so I found this book on Algorithms, the famous CLRS. However, I can't seem to get the correct answer to problem 1-1. The text goes like this: For each function f(n) and time t in the following table, determine the largest size n of a problem that can be solved in time t, assuming that the algorithm to solve the problem takes f(n) microseconds.

The problem is that when i try to find the solution of n log n of 10^6 i get different answer than every one else i get 87847.9 and the anser that i saw in other places is 6.24×10^4.
To try to find the solution i implemented a script in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double miliseconds = pow(10, 6);
    double high = pow(10, 6) * 10; // Increase the upper limit
    double low {};
    double mid {};
    double n {};

    while (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (mid * log(mid) < miliseconds)
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    n = high;
    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output shoul'd be 6.24×10^4 but i still get 87847.9
My question is how can i resolve that? why my method is incorrect ?

I can't understand how to configure my code to get te correct answer that shoul'd be 6.24×10^4 but i still get 87847.9.

Comment: Who said it's 6.24×10^4? I think that's wrong.

Comment: Do you want to solve `n log n = 10^6` for `n`? Bear in mind that C++ `log` function computes the natural logarithm but you want base 2 logarithm.

Comment: The sites where i found the answers are: https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/Ch1.pdf in the bottom of the page and here https://github.com/Kelvinson/CLRS-1/blob/master/docs/Chap01/Problems/1-1.md

Comment: The first of those doesn't say that.

Comment: And both of them say "n lg n", not "n log n".

Comment: Btw you seem to confuse micro, milli and mili. Better be more careful with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this problem, but I took a guess and recognized that

Instead of this:

```
if (mid * log(mid) < miliseconds)
```

It should be:

```
if ((mid * log(mid))/log(2) < miliseconds)
```

That prints out 62747.

Also, don't use floating point `double` types when `long long` integer type will do. Works better for all kinds of reasons and avoids edge cases with floating point.

Comment: Can't we just use `log2`?

Comment: I learn something new every day.

Comment: 62747 differs from 6.24×10^4.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  But it's the best guess given the limited information the OP has given. :)

Comment: Yeah, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3490239/750930) seems to have an explanation for 6.24×10^4, but I can't really judge it without seeing the problem text (and perhaps more context). To me, that value just looks wrong.

Comment: Yes. this answer is correct because in cs the logs are of base 2, thanks a lot !!